# bottle.py stalls when client disconnects

Tags: python, performance, bottle

I have a python server written with bottle. When I access the server from a website using Ajax, and then close the website before the server can send its response, the server gets stuck trying to send the response to a destination that no longer exists. When this happens, the server becomes unresponsive to any requests for about 10 seconds, before resuming normal operations.

How can I prevent this? I would like bottle to immediately stop trying if the website that made the request no longer exists.

I start the server like this:

```
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=port_to_listen_to, quiet=True)
```

and the only url exposed by the server is this:

```
@bottle.route('/', method='POST')
def main_server_input():
    request_data = bottle.request.forms['request_data']
    request_data = json.loads(request_data)
    try:
        response_data = process_message_from_scenario(request_data)
    except:
        error_message = utilities.get_error_message_details()
        error_message = "Exception during processing of command:\n%s" % (error_message,)
        print(error_message)
        response_data = {
            'success' : False,
            'error_message' : error_message,
        }
    return(json.dumps(response_data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `process_message_from_scenario` a long-running function? (Say, 10 seconds?)

If so, your one-and-only server thread will be tied up in that function, and no subsequent requests will be serviced during that time. Have you tried running a concurrent server, like gevent? Try this:

```
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=port_to_listen_to, quiet=True, server='gevent')
```

Comment: using gevent fixed it.